# How to activate single-click to navigate to fullscreen application?

Tags: dock, spaces, fullscreen

I am currently on macOS Big Sur and if I have a fullscreen application open (another space) I can't simply single-click on the Dock icon to navigate to this space.

**I have to double click the Dock icon to navigate to the fullscreen application.**

Is there an easy workaround to change it to single-click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under macOS Monterey (and maybe even in earlier versions), go to `Settings > Mission Control` and activate the checkbox on `When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open Windows for the application`

[image]